# Shinobi Android Library Multiple graphs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, shinobi

I am using Shinobi Android library to create different graphs like pie,bar and etc.
I have a childFragment (Created dynamically) , In that fragment I want to place multiple graphs one below other. For that I have created a LinearLayout with vertical orientation within a ScrollView. My plan is to adding graphs or charts one by one as childs of LinearLayout. This plan is not working, No matter how many children I added only one child is visible. This is happening only for Shinobi graphs views, If I add buttons or any other views I can see all the children when I scroll.

**Problem Point**: How can I insert multiple shinobi graphs one over the other in a Linearlayout?

Fragment Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/messageCard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/messageLabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:text="Message:"
                        android:textColor="@color/accent_material_light"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/messageTextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/messageLabel" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, this question you should send to author of Shinobi graph library. Catch him on Github and create issue. Unfortunately, I have no experience with this one, so I can't help you deal with this problem

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

I work for ShinobiControls and placing multiple charts in a ScrollView is a fairly common use case. We have seen a number of successful implementations of this in the past, so I suspect this may simply be an issue with your layout.
I appreciate that you have posted the layout in which you demonstrate that multiple non-shinobi Views can be added to a ScrollView. Could you please post the layout file which includes the ShinobiCharts? This should help us spot the cause, and if necessary we can try it here at ShinobiHQ.
Thanks,
Kai.

Comment: Hi Kai, thanks for the response. I am not statically adding shinobni chart fragment. I am dynamically creating ChartView and adding to LinearLayout which is there in the ScrollView.

Comment: Hi. Could you please post the code in which you instantiate your ChartView and add to the LinearLayout? Thanks.